# Calculate date in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am trying to calculate a date within an SQL query which is the date_required add the number of days in despatchdate - I am currently getting the error Invalid column name 'despatchdays'. If the despatchdays is null or "" then I want it to default to -14.

```
SELECT order_no, order_line_no, currency, product, address1,description, date_required, 
(SELECT despatchdays 
 FROM scheme.PDBtblSuppliers 
 WHERE SupplierIDFK = dbo.qryArrears2.supplier) AS despatchdays,
DATEADD(d, despatchdays, date_required) AS despatchdate
FROM  dbo.qryArrears2
```

How can I optimise this to get it working ?

I am using SQL 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT order_no
    , order_line_no
    , currency
    , product
    , address1
    ,description
    , date_required 
    , DATEADD(day, coalesce(pd.despatchdays, -14), date_required) AS despatchdate
FROM  dbo.qryArrears2 qa
INNER JOIN scheme.PDBtblSuppliers pd On pd.SupplierIDFK = qa.supplier
```

But it may give you more rows if there are several rows in PDBtblSuppliers for a supplier in qryArrears2.

You can also move despatchdate query inside the DATEADD:

```
SELECT * FROM (    
    SELECT order_no
    , order_line_no
        , currency
        , product
        , address1
        , description
        , date_required
        , DATEADD(day
            ,  coalesce((SELECT despatchdays FROM scheme.PDBtblSuppliers WHERE SupplierIDFK = qa.supplier), -14)
            , date_required
        ) AS despatchdate
    FROM  dbo.qryArrears2 qa
) as d 
WHERE despatchdate = '20150101'
```

`coalesce(despatchdays, -14)` will replace `despatchdays` by `-14` if `despatchdays` is NULL.

If `date_required` is a (var)char, you should replace it by a date in your table or cast is to data(time): CAST(date_required as date)

Comment: I remove AS despatchdays because it is not needed anymore in query 2

Comment: Great thank you - only this is now if there is no match in the PDBtblSuppliers table its coming up blank - if its eof can we default to -14 too ?

Comment: I Move coalesce out of the select. It was misplaced.

Comment: OK thanks :) - How can I search by the new despatchdate field and add a date into the where clause ? I get the error The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94931/discussion-between-emma-and-julien-vavasseur).

Comment: Invalid column name 'despatchdate' from where clause - guess I might have to swap to the join after all.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just `JOIN` the table and then use it like this:

```
SELECT 
  order_no, 
  order_line_no, 
  currency, 
  product, 
  address1,
  description, 
  date_required, 
  despatchdays,
  DATEADD(d, despatchdays, date_required) AS despatchdate
FROM  
  dbo.qryArrears2
JOIN scheme.PDBtblSuppliers
    ON SupplierIDFK = dbo.qryArrears2.supplier
```

**Update:**

You can cast the `date_required` to a `datetime` like this:

```
CAST(date_required AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Thanks Arion, just trying it now - The field date_required isn't a date field, how can I CAST it as one ?

Comment: @Emma : Updated the answer